# Spring-cloud-stream cannot produce kafka message

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud

I am trying to send messages to Kafka by using spring-cloud-stream but `send` method yields the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:403) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
...
```

App.java

```
package com.example.demostream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class DemoStreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoStreamApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> produce("hello there!");
    }


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("output")
    MessageChannel outputChannel;
    public void produce(String payload) {
        outputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).build());
    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-stream</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-stream</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

I am running Kafka inside a docker container as issuing the command:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=127.0.0.1 --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

But I am able to consume and produce messages if I use spring-kafka instead of spring-cloud-stream. So, what is the problem with spring-cloud-stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of client/broker version mismatch. I guess you are using Apache Kafka version 0.10.x. You have to use Apache Kafka 0.11.x or later to use with spring-cloud-stream(from version 2).

Comment: indeed, it was solved when I switched to Kafka 1.x version. 

for those who want to run kafka 1.x, the following docker image can be used.
```docker run -d \
           --name kafka \
           -p 9092:9092 \
           -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost \
           -e KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="test-topic:1:1" \
           blacktop/kafka```